# getting an error in author.php when displaying author meta's

Tags: wordpress, author

I created my own author.php template. I want to display author's custom meta fields Code samples is in this image : http://prntscr.com/wsdsa

But Wordpress doesnt display anything ? What should i do ?

```
                <div class="BCol">
                    <?php echo keepAuthorImage(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="ACol">
                    <div class="A1"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('first_name') ?> <?php echo get_the_author_meta('last_name') ?></div>
                    <div class="A2"><?php echo the_author_meta('job') ?></div>
                    <div class="A3"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('location') ?></div>
                    <div class="A5">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_author_meta('userwebpages') ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo THEME; ?>/_assets/_img/websiteicon.png" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php echo get_the_author_meta('twitter') ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo THEME; ?>/_assets/_img/twitteric.png" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="http://instagram.com/<?php echo get_the_author_meta('instagram') ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo THEME; ?>/_assets/_img/instagramic.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="A4"><?php echo get_the_author_meta('aboute') ?></div>
                </div>
```

Any helps ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress have pre defined variables, as

> $cat
>
> $tag

etc.
you have to use

> $author

to make your process.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing wrong is you are not using your get_the_author_meta() function in side the loop so you need to specify the author id.

either use the function in side your loop or use simple as below code

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$uid=$current_user->ID;
?>
```

change your function author meta as

```
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('first_name',$uid) ?>
```

for all your author meta for more help you can check reference code http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta

Comment: thank you so much but i have lot of authors, on my project i want to display their profile data on author.php ? Actually i really dont need current user id, i just need to get Author id when you view ?author=1 (e.g)